# Connected set on complex plane

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponential-function, connectedness

What's the numebr of connected components for the set of complex numbers $\{e^z:|z|=1\}$ on the complex plane?

Remark: It represents a simple closed curve which intersects the real axis at points $(\frac{1}{e},0)$ and $(e,0)$, so I think the number of connected components is 1.

Answer (score 5):

Notice that the function $f(z)= e^z$ is continuous and the fact that $A=\{z||z|=1 \}$ is connected. Therefore $f(A)=\{e^z | |z|=1\}$ is connected.